# CAS LDAP Search Subtree

Tags: ldap, cas, jasig

I'm using last version of Jasig CAS server (4.0.0) with an LDAP server.

Users are stored under this LDAP structure : `ou=Users,ou=SSOTEST,dc=mycompany,dc=com`

What I want is to search an user from a top level (example : `ou=SSOTEST,dc=mycompany,dc=com`).

CAS server has an `LdapPersonAttributeDao` bean which is looking for an object matching a search filter. Here is the code for this bean :

```
<bean id="ldapPersonAttributeDao"
      class="org.jasig.cas.persondir.LdapPersonAttributeDao"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="searchPooledLdapConnectionFactory"
      p:baseDN="ou=SSOTEST,dc=company,dc=com"
      p:searchControls-ref="searchControls"
      p:searchFilter="uid={0}">
    <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
        <map>
            <!--
               | Key is LDAP attribute name, value is principal attribute name.
               -->
            <entry key="memberOf" value="userMemberOf" />
            <entry key="cn" value="userCn" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And now the `searchControls` bean which do a lookup at `SUBTREE_SCOPE` (2) level (according to`SearchControls` scope level values).

```
<bean id="searchControls"
      class="javax.naming.directory.SearchControls"
      p:searchScope="2"
      p:countLimit="10" />
```

When I run my CAS server and I try to authenticate, everything works but there are no extra attributes returned.
I think the problem comes from searchScope, which don't seems to be set to wanted value.
Here is output log from the server :

`<execute request=[org.ldaptive.SearchRequest@-1312441815::baseDn=ou=SSOTEST,dc=mycompany,dc=com, searchFilter=[org.ldaptive.SearchFilter@-3391
91059::filter=uid={0}, parameters={0=myuser}], returnAttributes=[], searchScope=null, timeLimit=0, sizeLimit=10 [...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know its been some time since this question was asked. But I managed to fix this problem by adding:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

to deployerConfigContext.xml.

The cause of this issue was that the initalize method in LdapPersonAttributeDao was not being invoked because the @PostConstruct annotation wasn't being executed. For this reason the searchScope variable was never set.

Comment: Necromancy is [not discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think it will help other CAS users ! Since it was a long time a go, we just chose to build a custom implementation of `LdapPersonAttributeDao` to solve this.